Replace values from one vector in dataframe with other values, based on a condition in another vector, in R
I have a dataframe, "grp_wqdata, that is grouped by the vector "CHEMICAL_NAME":
structure(list(SAMPLE_ID = c("Sampe 1", "Sampe 2", "Sampe 3", 
"Sampe 4", "Sampe 5", "Sampe 6", "Sampe 7", "Sampe 8", "Sampe 9", 
"Sampe 10", "Sampe 11", "Sampe 12"), CHEMICAL_NAME = c("LEAD", 
"LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", 
"LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD"), REPORT_RESULT_VALUE = c(0.769, 0.512, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT = c("0.0100", 
"0.0100", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", 
"0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500"), DETECT_FLAG = c("Y", "Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

If the value in vector DETECT_FLAG is "N", then I would like to replace the value that is in  REPORT_RESULT_VALUE on that row with the value in REPORT_RESULT_LIMIT in that row.
I have tried the following:
ifelse("N" %in% grp_wqdata$DETECT_FLAG,
       replace(grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE, 
               grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE[match(grp_wqdata$DETECT_FLAG == "N")],
               grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_LIMIT[match(grp_wqdata$DETECT_FLAG == "N")]),
       -999)#end of ifelse

but I continue to get the error

Error in match(grp_wqdata$DETECT_FLAG == "N") : 
  argument "table" is missing, with no default


Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this without a for loop?

You don't need replace since ifelse can handle the conditional match and replacement.

grp_wqdata <- structure(list(SAMPLE_ID = c("Sampe 1", "Sampe 2", "Sampe 3", 
"Sampe 4", "Sampe 5", "Sampe 6", "Sampe 7", "Sampe 8", "Sampe 9", 
"Sampe 10", "Sampe 11", "Sampe 12"), CHEMICAL_NAME = c("LEAD", 
"LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", 
"LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD"), REPORT_RESULT_VALUE = c(0.769, 0.512, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT = c("0.0100", 
"0.0100", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", 
"0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500"), DETECT_FLAG = c("Y", "Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))


grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE <- ifelse(
     grp_wqdata$DETECT_FLAG == 'N',
     grp_wqdata$REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT, 
     grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE)

   SAMPLE_ID CHEMICAL_NAME REPORT_RESULT_VALUE REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT DETECT_FLAG
   <chr>     <chr>         <chr>               <chr>                         <chr>      
 1 Sampe 1   LEAD          0.769               0.0100                        Y          
 2 Sampe 2   LEAD          0.512               0.0100                        Y          
 3 Sampe 3   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 4 Sampe 4   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 5 Sampe 5   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 6 Sampe 6   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 7 Sampe 7   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 8 Sampe 8   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
 9 Sampe 9   LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
10 Sampe 10  LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
11 Sampe 11  LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N          
12 Sampe 12  LEAD          0.500               0.500                         N  


Here's how to understand understand what's going on.
If DETECT_FLAG == 'N': Then take the value from REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT.
Otherwise: Take the value from  REPORT_RESULT_VALUE
Also, you'll probably want to convert REPORT_VALUE_VALUE and REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT to numeric vectors.
Also, as Jilber pointed out in the comments, we can use with to avoid having to use grp_wqdata$ over and over.
grp_wqdata$REPORT_RESULT_VALUE <- with(grp_wqdata, 
                                       ifelse(
                                         DETECT_FLAG == 'N',
                                         REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT, 
                                         REPORT_RESULT_VALUE))

When you pass a data.frame as the first argument to with, you can then refer to the columns in your data.frame without having to prefix them with the data.frame name and $ or [[.

You can avoid calling grp_wqdata too many times if you use with as in: with(grp_wqdata, ifelse(DETECT_FLAG == 'N',REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT, REPORT_RESULT_VALUE))

Excellent point!

You can use either but I think within() is better than with() to add a column to a data frame - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827572/what-is-the-difference-between-with-and-within-in-r#comment33035908_21827572 . In any case I'd use transform() over both here.

Yeah those are good options. I usually use dplyr::mutate.

You need to do the following thing
library(dplyr)

grp_wqdata <- structure(list(
  SAMPLE_ID = c("Sampe 1", "Sampe 2", "Sampe 3", "Sampe 4", "Sampe 5", "Sampe 6", "Sampe 7", "Sampe 8", "Sampe 9", "Sampe 10", "Sampe 11", "Sampe 12"),
  CHEMICAL_NAME = c("LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD", "LEAD"),
  REPORT_RESULT_VALUE = c(0.769, 0.512, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
  REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT = c("0.0100", "0.0100", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500", "0.500"),
  DETECT_FLAG = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

grp_wqdata <- grp_wqdata %>%
  mutate(REPORT_RESULT_VALUE = if_else(DETECT_FLAG == "N", as.numeric(REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT), REPORT_RESULT_VALUE))

print(grp_wqdata)


which gives
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   SAMPLE_ID CHEMICAL_NAME REPORT_RESULT_VALUE REPORT_METHOD_DETECTION_LIMIT DETECT_FLAG
   <chr>     <chr>                       <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>      
 1 Sampe 1   LEAD                        0.769 0.0100                        Y          
 2 Sampe 2   LEAD                        0.512 0.0100                        Y          
 3 Sampe 3   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 4 Sampe 4   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 5 Sampe 5   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 6 Sampe 6   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 7 Sampe 7   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 8 Sampe 8   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
 9 Sampe 9   LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
10 Sampe 10  LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
11 Sampe 11  LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N          
12 Sampe 12  LEAD                        0.5   0.500                         N     

